# SlewRate and Output Swing for a differential OpAmp

Tags: operational-amplifier, slew-rate

I want to calculate SR and output swing for a fully differential OpAmp, using simulation.

I came across this solution for a single-ended OpAmp:
A. SR calculation:
[image: SR Calculation]

B. swing - make 'Vin' in the above a sine-wave source, and increase Vin amplitude to the point where the output is not distorted, than extract the swing.

So first - is this method acceptable [A,B or both]?
if so - how can I match this for a fully diff OpAmp? I can't understand how to set both inputs/outputs. Let's please use this notation:
[image: input and output notations]

The OpAmp topology that I'm using is:
[image: Fully diff OpAmp with linear MOSFETs]

if the above method is wrong - what would you recommend?

Thank you very much,
Daniel

Comment: Why don't you tell us the diff amp you want to use so at least you get a more practical answer.

Comment: It's been an hour now and no response from you so I'm voting to close this question down as lacking information. Daniel take note - this is a fast moving (normally) site and comments get raised very quickly with regards lack of information provided by the OP so it is good practice to stick around for at least an hour to service queries.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Andy, as for your question - I don't need this for actual use or practical reason but for theory

Comment: I hear what you say but without defining what the transfer function is of the diff amp picture you show at the bottom of the question, then this is unanswerable. There is no generic diff amp symbol with an unambiguous TF. You have attempted to show one but only assumptions and guesses can be made about it.

Comment: I can't analyse these characteristics (SR/swing) only with observations and measurements, using simulation (I mean as if the OpAmp is a "black box")? Anyway I've added the topology, as I understand this is necessary. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SR rate is correct. Take a look on https://payhip.com/b/5Srt ("ch.  1.4.  Slew-rate" in a paid version. I have that position at hand, so I'm using the info from it.):

[image: slew rate 1]

[image: slew rate 2]

[image: slew rate 3]

or any other position like Razavi or Baker (http://www.designers-guide.org/Books/).

What you need for fully differential opamp is the feedback. If you will use your opamp like in your 2nd picture (when you define names for inputs and outputs), you have a comparator. SR is still possible to be calculated (you need take into account the offset and set outputs to the desired level, e.g. VDD/2), but with the feedback it is easier and this is how you are using your opamp so you can get real results. Once you have feedback, you just apply input voltages to vi1 and vi2 in the opposite directions (e.g. pulse voltages as in the picture you provided or Fig. 1.21 above) and calculate slew-rate on raising and falling edges.

For the output swing, THD parameter may be used. It is described in "ch. 1.1.2.  Output voltage range" in a paid version of https://payhip.com/b/5Srt, but you should be able to find it somewhere else like here:

- https://ecedmans.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/the-operational-amplifier.pdf
- http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~jones/es154/pdf/op_amp.pdf

But still, you should have a feedback path. You just apply input sinusoidal signals and measure THD on your outputs.

Comment: No problem. Happy to be able to help you. :)